# Proof of partial autocorrelation function for MA Model

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, moving-average

I am reading the book [Introductory Econometric for Finance](http://www.cambridge.org/hk/academic/subjects/economics/finance/introductory-econometrics-finance-3rd-edition?format=PB&isbn=9781107661455#wKxsyBstAYtUmJMW.97), and there is a formula for finding partial autocorrelation function at lag 2:

$$\tau_{22}=(\tau_2-\tau_1^2)/(1-\tau_1^2)$$

where $\tau_k$ is the autocorrelation for lag k and $\tau_{kk}$ is partial autocorrelation for lag k.

This formula works but I have no ideas how to derive this. Also, the author says for lags greater than two, the formulae are complex, so that not showing in the book. Can someone show me the formula? Or is there any books that is good for learning about time series?

Answer (score -2):

Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples, from Shumway and Stoffer is a nice book for time series analysis.

It can be downloaded from:
http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/

Chapter gives a clear inside in ACF and PACF. Can't find the equation you mention though.